# C++ unordered_map/map [] operator default initialization value

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am wondering if this is a standard that calling [] without assignment will initialize the value of this key-value pair to be 0, if value is of type int?

```
    // the way I did before, can I skip the if() checking?
    std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t>  word_map;
    for (const auto &w : { "this", "sentence", "is", "not", "a", "sentence",
                           "this", "sentence", "is", "a", "hoax"}) {
        if (!word_map.count(w)) {
            word_map[w] = 0;
        } else {
            ++word_map[w];
        }
    }
```

Can i do the following instead:

```
    std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t>  word_map;
    for (const auto &w : { "this", "sentence", "is", "not", "a", "sentence",
                           "this", "sentence", "is", "a", "hoax"}) {
        ++word_map[w];
    }
```

Thanks.

```
/*-------------
---------------
-------------*/
```

UPDATES:

I just checked out this page about en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization it seems that if we reply on the default initialization int x; the value of x will be indeterminate. So I guess word_map[w] does not necessarily == 0 when first called?

Comment: See [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). The same applies to `unordered_map`. The crucial detail is that the value `T()` is inserted.

Comment: @juanchopanza Don't you mean... The value that is inserted? ;) I'll see myself out...

Comment: @rwols I don't follow :-P

Comment: @juanchopanza you edited your comment! Now my comment doesn't make sense. Oh well.

Comment: @rwols Yeah, sorry. But thanks for pointing out it the original may have been confusing.

Comment: I see, T() is inserted. Thanks!!

Comment: I guess T() for double is 0.0 and for string is "". Or is there a T() for primitive types like int, double?

Comment: I just checked out this page about http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization   it seems that if we reply on the default initialization int x; the value of x will be indeterminate. So I guess word_map[w] does not necessarily == 0 when first called?

Comment: @JohnTan `T()` is called *value initialization*, not *default initialization*. That means zero-initialization got built-ins. Unfortunately the answers in the duplicate are all terrible and don't explain this properly.